# Run function while condition is true but need to retest condition each time?

Tags: jquery

I have lots of results in a list. this.label designates how many results should be in each row.

Sometimes the wrong number of results are in the row. I can find this out with this code:

```
var noResults = $(".results").length;

if (this.label == "3") {
  var ratio = (noResults / 3);
  if (ratio % 1 !== 0) {
    console.log('Wrong number of results');
  }
}
if (this.label == "4") {
  var ratio = (noResults / 4);
  if (ratio % 1 !== 0) {
    console.log('Wrong number of results');
  }
}
```

I have a function called addResult which will add another item. When the wrong number of results are in a row I want to keep calling this function and adding a result until the row is full. How can I call addResult instead of my alert and also check again if the row is full, and if isnt then add another result (and so on)?

Comment: make a runnable piece of code here. Just click the button in the editor to add runnable script

Comment: seems that you need a recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `if` to a `while`. Just make sure that the ratio will at some point be correct!

```
function getratio(divby) {
  return ($(".results").length / divby);
}

if (this.label == "3") {
  while (getratio(3) % 1 !== 0) {
    addResult();
  }
}

if (this.label == "4") {
  while (getratio(4) % 1 !== 0) {
    addResult();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call each function inside other ones:

```
function checkLength(){
var noResults = $(".results").length;

if (this.label == "3") {
  var ratio = (noResults / 3);
  if (ratio % 1 !== 0) {
    console.log('Wrong number of results');
    addResult();
  }
}
if (this.label == "4") {
  var ratio = (noResults / 4);
  if (ratio % 1 !== 0) {
    console.log('Wrong number of results');
    addResult();
  }
}
}

function addResult(){
//Some codes here;
.
.
checkLength() // to check again
}
```